# After update some info, return to specific paginated page - Laravel 4

Tags: forms, laravel-4, pagination, redirect, response.redirect

I have this case:

A page in laravel 4 with paginate (10 items per page), and for instance, if I'm on page 2, I want to edit some item. I click in the item and I go to the specific form to update. After update, i want to redirect the application to the specific paginated page that I was on before, i.e. page 2. I tried to use  `URL::Previous();` but, if for instance, my validation of the form fire up, the previous page will be the page of the form, and not the paginated page, and then i will be stuck :/

Any ideas?
(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Why dont you submit the form with ajax, and then manipulate the redirections with javascript?

Comment: I would prefer via laravel :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could store the page number in the session and then use it when you want to redirect.

```
$url = 'url?page=' . Session::get('page_number');
return Redirect::to($url);
```

This is probably not the best way to do it but it should work.

Comment: yeah, that works. But even so, I would like something more beautiful (If you know what I mean) :)

Answer (score 2):

1. add to you form:
   `{{ Form::hidden('redirects_to', URL::previous()) }}`
2. in controller you can return like this: 
   `return Redirect::to(Input::get('redirects_to'));`
3. note this only apply with larave 4

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="last_url" value="{{  URL::previous() }}">
```

I use this in the `Controller`:

```
return  redirect()->to($request->last_url)->with('success','Post Updated Successfully');
```